# Lib tool not able to create archive

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using `libBilldesk.a` library in my project for payment option.
As I am using `TPKeyboarAvoidingScrollView` file in my project and also same file exist in `libBilldesk.a` static library because of which I am getting duplicate symbol error at compile time. So to resolve this issue I am trying to remove `TPKeyboarAvoidingScrollView.o` file from libBilldesk file.

But I am getting following error message on terminal
error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `o' in: -output

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the complete command?

Comment: libtool -static *.o -output ../libBilldesk-arm64.a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct parameter for the output file is `-o` instead of `-output`:

```
libtool -static -o ../libBilldesk-arm64.a *.o
```

See manpage of `libtool`for details.

Comment: Hi, I am using payTm sdk also. what I have to do in that is to remove Reachability file from static library . But paytm static library is exec file

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. If you mean it has set the executable flag you shouldn't care about. A static lib is in `ar`(1) format. You list its contents with `ar t libfile.a`.